# free the pointer memory after the function call

Tags: c

I am having simple doubt regarding the memory leak and memory free in C. Here is my simple example

```
typedef struct{
     uint16 a;
     uint8 b[3];
     uint8 c;
}log_msg;

typedef struct node{
     log_msg list;
     struct node *next;
}logs_t;
```

This is the structure I have. If I store the Data in the structure. Then if I want to access the structure with a pointer to check the list of msg_log. It is necessary to de allocate the pointer/ free it. Example,

```
ret = Check_the_list(data);

uint8 Check_the_list(uint16 data)
{
     logs_t *ptr = NULL;
     uint8 brk = 0;
     ptr = top;
     while(ptr != NULL && brk == 0)
     {
        if(ptr->list.a == data)
        {
            brk = 1;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
     }
     return 1;
  }
```

It is necessary to de allocate/free ptr here.This will cause memory leaks, if this function calls multiple number of times and I am not freeing the ptr?. As I know, this will de allocate automatically after function call, because I am not using dynamic memory. But even though I want to confirm with experts. So I request experts to suggest me.

Comment: What is the purpose of the brk variable if you are returning right after setting it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't have to `free()` anything as you haven't allocated any memory for `ptr` in `Check_the_list()`.

The easy way to remember is whenever you do a `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()`, then you do a `free()`.

Aside: Your loop condition using `brk` is not necessary as you return immediately after finding data. So `brk == 0` needless and you could eliminate `brk` completely:

```
 while(ptr != NULL)
     {
        if(ptr->list.a == data)
        {
         return 0;
        }
        else
        {
         ptr = ptr->next;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `ptr` is a number allocated on the stack that contains an address. The stack is "freed" when your function returns. There is nothing else to free.

You should do the same number of `free` that the number of `malloc`. If you do no `malloc`, you should not free anything. If you try to free `ptr`, it will free the element pointed by `ptr` which is not something you want.